# How to get a User to select a plan and be dynamically created in the next page (form)

Tags: php, jquery

I'd like users to select a plan and the information selected is dynamically applied to the next page and also stored where I can email with the users information entered in a form.

```
<div class="pricing_box">
  <h3><a href="#">PROFESSIONAL</a></h3>
  <div class="price-value">
    <a href="#">$300.00/month</a>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dolor sitamet, Consect</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Adipiscing elit</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Proin commodo turips</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Laws pulvinarvel</a></li>
    <li><a href="tables.html">More Details</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="cart">
    <a class="popup-with-zoom-anim" href="contact.html">Buy now</a>
  </div>
</div><!--pricing_box-->



<form id="myForm" action="process.php" method="POST">
<label for="humans" class="humans">Human check: Leave this field empty</label>
<input type="text" name="humans" id="humans" class="humans" />
<h1 class="intro">Professional Edition - Sign Up Today</h1>
<div class="form_style_wrapper">
<label>*Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="full_name" class="contact_first_name" title="please enter you Full 
Name" />
</div><!--end of form_style_wrapper-->
<div class="form_style_wrapper">
<label>*Email:</label>
<input type="email" name="email" class="contact_email" title="Please specify your email" /> 

</div><!--end of form_style_wrapper-->
<div class="form_style_wrapper">
<label>*Phone:</label>
<input type="tel" name="phone" class="contact_telephone" title="Please enter you mobile or telephone number" />
</div><!--end of form_style_wrapper-->
<div class="form_style_wrapper">
<label>*Company:</label>
<input type="text" name="company" class="contact_company" title="Please enter you Companies Name" />
</div><!--end of form_style_wrapper-->
<div class="form_style_wrapper">
<label for="comments">Comments:</label>
<textarea name="comments" class="contact-info" id="message"></textarea>
</div><!--end of form_style_wrapper-->
<button name="send" class="send" type="submit">Send</button> 
</form>
```

I have 3 other choices, Professional, Basic, Standard etc. (same box)
Instead of making an additional 3 pages (forms) can I create one page and have the users selection stored dynamically? If chosen Professional, then Professional Form (title appears - same form for all) and can in PHP will I still capture the chosen field so I can email with the users current selection?

Comment: For each field you want to populate, add this in the php code of the second page `value="<?php print $yourValue; ?>"`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not so clear so I will attempt to answer. If you don't want to create 3 pages you can use [$_GET][1] to change the content of your page.

For example, you can do something like

```
if ( isset($_GET['plan']) ) //check if the plan page is set
{
    if ($_GET['plan'] == "pro") {
        //Display Professional page here
    } elseif ($_GET['plan'] == "basic") {
        //Display Basic page here
    } elseif ($_GET['plan'] == "standard") {
        //Display Standard page here
    } else {
        echo 'The selected plan is invalid.'; //Display error message or whatever
    }
}
else
{
    //Display initial page here
}
```

And your URL would look like http://yourwebsite.com/index.php?plan=pro
[1]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to pass a GET variable to the second page. A GET variable is passed through the url like so :

`http://yoursite.com/page.php?myVar=3`

So If the user chooses a plan by clicking links, do it like so :

```
<a href="page.php?plan=1">First plan</a>
<a href="page.php?plan=2">Second plan</a>
```

Then, on you second page, to retrieve that value, use `$_GET['plan']`. For example

```
<?php
switch($_GET['plan']){
    case "1": $title="First plan";
              break;
    case "2": $title="Second plan";
              break;
    //In case the value is not given, or incorrect
    default: print "Error, no plan selected";
             exit();
}
?>

<FORM blablabla
    ...
 <h1 class="intro"><?=$title?></h1>
    ...
</FORM>
```

This way you associate a number to a plan, and fill the form with the associated data.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed solution. I've tried to utilize it and in the url it does say contact.php?plan=3. However, the $title doesn't appear in the form page? Have I missed something.

Comment: @bodiebanderas No problem, can you post the code of the second page? Or add it to your question as a solution you tried.

Comment: <h1 class="intro"><? =$title ?></h1>

Comment: switch($_GET['plan']){
   case "1": $title="Basic Edition - Sign Up Today";
break; //x 4 plans etc

Comment: @bodiebanderas My bad! I added spaces to make it more readable, but there needs to be no spaces! Edited my answer.

Comment: @bodiebanderas I can't edit my comment, but I am talking about `<?=$title?>`. I discovered that no spaces are allowed for this syntax. It can also be written as `<?php print $title; ?>` with spaces. You choose ;)